# Isotope with Filter Count and imagesLoaded

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope, imagesloaded

I have a large grid of objects that I'm filtering with [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). I'm using combination filters and a search box, and I'm also using imagesLoaded (necessary because of the large number of items). That all works ok.

I also want to print the number of items filtered. I followed instructions [here](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/pbkbBO)

And here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// quick search regex
var qsRegex;

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.status',
    getSortData: {
        name: '.elemsort',
    },
    sortBy : 'name',
});
});

var iso = $grid.data('isotope');
var $filterCount = $('.filter-count');

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

$('.filtersbutton').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
    // combine filters
    var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
    // set filter for Isotope
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    updateFilterCount();
});

// bind filter on select change
$('.filterstextsearch').on( 'change', '.button-group', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var filterGroup = $this.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter');
    // combine filters
    var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
    // set filter for Isotope
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    updateFilterCount();
    $(':selected', this).addClass('is-checked').siblings().removeClass('is-checked')
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', '.button', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
    var value = '';
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
        value += obj[ prop ];
    }
    return value;
}

// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.isofilter').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $grid.isotope({
        filter: function() {
            return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
        }
    });
    updateFilterCount();
}, 200 ) );

function updateFilterCount() {
  $filterCount.text( iso.filteredItems.length + ' items' );
}

updateFilterCount();    

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  return function debounced() {
    if ( timeout ) {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
    }
    function delayed() {
      fn();
      timeout = null;
    }
    timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
  }
}
});
```

I suspect the reason it doesn't work is that I use imagesLoaded? In console I get "TypeError: iso is undefined". But I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, 2 days later, I managed to find a solution by myself. The problem was because of imagesLoaded. So I replaced the "// init Isotope" portion of the code like this and now the counts are working.

```
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.breakdown').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.status',
    getSortData: {
        name: '.elementsort',
    },
    sortBy : 'name',
});

$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

The issue with this option is that the page is much slower to load now than when I initialized Isotope after all images were loaded. If anyone has a solution to this, it would be much appreciated.